# how to force core data reload from persistent storage after cellEdit

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I am having trouble reloading data from core data persistent storage after I edit a cell.

I tried reloading the tableView itself but that does not force a fetch from the persistent storage, how can I force a total reload?

Here is my attempt at reloading that does not work, if I exit the UIViewController and go back in all works so I know the persistent storage is updated correctly

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

    if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"TransactionListView:tableView:context = %@", context);
    }

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSManagedObject *transactionRow = [self.transactionRowsRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [transactionRow setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[@"999" intValue]] forKey:@"status"];
        [transactionRow setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[@"0" intValue]] forKey:@"qty"];
        [transactionRow setValue:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"] forKey:@"price"];
        [transactionRow setValue:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"] forKey:@"discountPercentage"];
        [transactionRow setValue:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"] forKey:@"discountAmount"];
        [transactionRow setValue:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"] forKey:@"amountTax"];
        [transactionRow setValue:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"] forKey:@"sum"];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                return;
            }
        }
        [self.transactionListViewTbl reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to mention this.

After read your question, it doesn't sounds to me that its going to be fixed using a Fetch Controller. Fetch Controller is pretty neat, it let you keep your tables updated without the need to explicitly call to [table reloadData]. But if reloading your Table the data didn't get updated, it might be possible that you have more that one Managed Object Context updating your Persistent Store.

The data is been updated by a different Managed Object Context and you are not getting the updates on the one that you connected your table. I would start by looking at my Core Data Stack and to the number of Managed Object Context. If you need to have more than 1, you can subscribe to the changes, or be sure that the changes that you want to see are done on the same Managed Object Context.

Hope it helps.

[Managed Object Context - Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/managedObjectContext.html)

Comment: I have a managed object context in every method, but in the same method I only have one, could it clash between methods? if so how can I make one that is persistent throughout all methods?

Comment: Thanks, I had two contexts competing I was a copy and paste error, to many late nights coding I thinks, appreciate the heads up on this.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of NSFetchedResultsController as your data source and implement NSFecthedResultsController delegates

You can create NSFetchedResults controller as a property in your viewController, create a single instance of it

```
lazy var transactionFetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController<Transaction> = {
        let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        var fetchedResultsController : NSFetchedResultsController< Transaction >!

        appdelegate.managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
            var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest< Transaction >
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                fetchRequest = Transaction.fetchRequest()
            } else {
                fetchRequest  = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Transaction")
            }

            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "your_property", ascending: true)]
            let yourPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "your condition == whatever")
            fetchRequest.predicate = yourPredicate
            fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: appdelegate.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        }
        return fetchedResultsController
    }()
```

set delegates to your viewController

```
self. transactionFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
```

Finally initialise it in viewDidLoad()

```
try! self. transactionFetchedResultsController.performFetch()
```

now implement the delegates :)

```
extension YourViewController : NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        //row updated
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        //section updated
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        //change completed
        //reload your tableView
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If in case you are wondering how to use NSFetchedResultsController as tableView data source ?

```
extension YourViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return (self. transactionFetchedResultsController.sections?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           //assuming you have only one section
           //you can always return number of items in each section using NSFetchedResultsController :)
            return (self. transactionFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //let cell = ....
        //you can instantiate your cell here
        //you can access your transaction as below
        let transaction = self. transactionFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row]
        //return your cell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: this looks great, I am trying to translate to ObjC

Comment: @matt-douhan : Sorry buddy dont have objective C code sample stopped working on it from quite a sometime now :(

Comment: @matt-douhan : Bingo :) Please consider accepting answer in case it works and helps you :)